# StateAccessViolation: Value must be a literal - Vyper Ethereum smart contract

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, vyper

#### Version Information

- vyper Version (output of `vyper --version`): 0.2.8+commit.069936f
- OS: osx
- Python Version (output of `python --version`): Python 2.7.16
- Environment (output of `pip freeze`):

```
altgraph==0.10.2
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
bonjour-py==0.3
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
numpy==1.8.0rc1
py2app==0.7.3
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013.7
scipy==0.13.0b1
six==1.4.1
xattr==0.6.4
```

this call of a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(self.some_uint256):
      # do something...
```

is throwing the error:
`StateAccessViolation: Value must be a literal`

full error output:

```
vyper.exceptions.StateAccessViolation: Value must be a literalvyper.exceptions.StateAccessViolation: Value must be a literal
contract "vyper-farm/contracts/Farm.vy", function "_employ", line 152:4
151
---> 152 for i in range(self.num_employees):
-------------^
153 pass
```

what exactly am i doing wrong?

is this a misunderstanding as to what a literal is on my part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue above is not one of misunderstanding the for loop's use, instead it is a result of incompatible coding style with the security measures of vyper

the reason the for loop was being created was to make sure when an 'employee' was 'fired' or 'quit' then there wouldn't be an empty record in the list of 'employee's which was being maintained

instead, in order to avoid using a for loop altogether, and with a small sacrifice of not being able to remove no longer 'active employee's, best practice is to just track the 'employee' in a hashmap:

```
idToEmployee: HashMap[uint256, employee]
```

and when tracking the employees, simply assign an `id` attribute to the 'employee' using a global variable called `num_employees`

ex:

```
def employ():
   new_employee: employee = employee ({
        id: self.num_employees
   })

   self.idToEmployee[self.num_employees] = new_employee
```

when attempting to view or update that employee's info simply use:

```
self.idToEmployee[id]
```

@vladimir has a good explanation of how range is passed variables if there is still confusion about `for` loops in vyper for the reader

Comment: This doesn't really answer OP's question. This just shows how to access a hashamp.

What is the recommended way (or equivalent) of looping through a hash map in vyper?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the description of [range](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/control-structures.html?highlight=range#range-iteration)-function, there just one way to pass a variable to it:

```py
for i in range(a, a + N):
    pass
```

In your case it should be like this (not sure that it be useful):

```py
num_employees: public(uint256)

@external
def __init__():
    self.num_employees = 16

@external
def do_smth():
    for i in range(self.num_employees, self.num_employees + 10):
        pass
```

Comment: `for i in range(0, 0 + self.num_employees): pass` causes this error message instead: `vyper.exceptions.InvalidType: Value must be a literal integervyper.exceptions.InvalidType: Value must be a literal integer` the difference being that it now asks for a literal integer rather than just a literal

Comment: also i am unsure what you mean by there being only one way to pass a variable to `range()`, the docs seem to show three ways to pass a variable

Comment: @LiamO'Toole Code Contract's languages (such as solidity, vyper, etc.) intentionally have many restrictions to avoid writing 'dangerous' code. About *range*: there are only three options to call it: 1) *range(literal_start)*, 2) *range(literal_start, literal_stop)* and 3) *range(variable_1, variable_1 + literal)*. Call *range(0, 0 + self.num_employees)* is not fit anyone so the error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can't use variables in `range()` directly, but we can use other method.

Here is my advice:

```
for i in range(999999):
    if i < self.some_uint256:
        # do something...
    else:
        break
```

Comment: while that is a workaround i would not suggest doing this as it opens up the case of a loop running for a large number of iterations which can cause highly bloated gas costs unexpectedly, this question is very old and the truth is looping in vyper should only be done with well thought out constraints on the iteration count